# Do Java semaphores use busy waiting or a wait/notify by default?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

As the question goes. I'm using the JDK 6.0 on Windows 7, and am attempting to use semaphores as a mechanism to solve a synchronization problem. It works perfectly, but I'm trying to avoid busy waiting in my problem.

I would just ask the java documentation and spare SO the trouble, but the docs go like this:

```html
Acquires the given number of permits from this semaphore,
 blocking until all are available, or the thread is interrupted.

Acquires the given number of permits, if they are available,
 and returns immediately, reducing the number of available permits
 by the given amount.

If insufficient permits are available then the current thread
 becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire(int)

That is to say, the docs seem to be implying both answers. Which one is correct?

Comment: most of the `java.util.concurrent` primitives rely on `java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` that is based on park/unpark, i.e. no busy spin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clearly wait/notify due to this line:

> If insufficient permits are available then the current thread becomes disabled 
>   for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant.

This means the thread is not scheduled by the OS until the event to wake it up (available semaphore permits) occurs, at which point the thread is signaled to continue execution.

Comment: it's park/unpark, not wait/notify as there is difference between: wait/notify requires synchronization (or contention), park/unpark - does not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how it's implying busy-waiting at all. It clearly states that the thread is "disabled" and dormant. Basically, it's cheap: the thread won't consume processor time while it's waiting to acquire the semaphore.

Comment: But a line above that, it says that the thread blocks while waiting, which seems to be contradictory.

Comment: Yes.  Blocking<>busy waiting. If a thread calls 'wait' on a semaphore with insufficient 'permits', the call does not return until another thread signals sufficient permits to satisfy the waiting thread.  It's exactly as Jon Skeet posts above - the thread is blocked during the wait and gets no CPU at all. Try it and see - block a looping thread on an empty semaphore and check CPU use - it will be zero.

Comment: @Faqa: As Martin says, blocking isn't the same as busy-waiting.